# DynamoDb to test put_item function in pytest

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, pytest

I am trying to test DynamoDB put_item in pytest using stub and getting error and also not sure about what will be expected_parameters in add_response.

```
def test_put_item_dynamodb(dynamodb_resource_stub, item_fake, condition_expression_fake, return_values_fake,
                       return_consumed_capacity_fake, return_item_metrics_fake):
        expected_params = {
                 'Item': item_fake,
                 'Condition_Expression': condition_expression_fake,
                 'Return_Values': return_values_fake,
                 'Return_Consumed_Capacity': return_consumed_capacity_fake,
                'return_item_collection_metrics': return_item_metrics_fake
         }

expected_response = {
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'RequestId': 'ABCD1234EFGH5678',
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'HTTPHeaders': {
            'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Mon, 01 Jan 2019 12:12:12 GMT',
            'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0',
            'content-length': '2',
            'connection': 'keep-alive',
            'x-amzn-requestid': 'ABCD1234EFGH5678',
            'x-amz-crc32': '12456789'
        },
        'RetryAttempts': 0
    }
}
input_response = deepcopy(expected_response)
dynamodb_resource_stub.add_response(method='put_item', service_response=input_response,
                                    expected_params=expected_params)
dynamodb_resource_stub.activate()
actual_response = src.lambda_handler.put_item_dynamodb_table(item=[item_fake],
                                                          condition_expression=condition_expression_fake,
                                                          return_values=return_values_fake,
                                                          return_consumed_capacity=return_consumed_capacity_fake,
                                                          return_item_collection_metrics=return_item_metrics_fake)
assert expected_response == actual_response
dynamodb_resource_stub.assert_no_pending_responses()
```

This is **error** -

```
TypeError: Unsupported type "<class 'function'>" for value "<function aws_request_id_fake at 0x1073776a8>"
```

**aws_request_id** - it is part of Item and when item_fake is called above error shows up, it seems aws_request_id_fake is not being called properly in test function.

```
  @fixture(scope='module')
  def aws_request_id_fake(request):
    return 'xyz789'


 @fixture(scope='module')
 def item_fake(request):
   return {
    'aws_request_id': aws_request_id_fake,
    'messageId': messageid_fake
}
```

Comment: The code you listed doesn't use `aws_request_id_fake`anywhere. Unclear where the error comes from.

Comment: @hoefling -  I have edited the description for expected_params and aws_request_id.

Comment: You need to pass the `aws_request_id_fake` fixture in `item_fake`'s arguments, e.g. `def item_fake(request, aws_request_id_fake): ...` Otherwise, you're using it as a function object.

Comment: Thanks @hoefling, it worked. I am not able to 'marked as answered'